# Configure (or mimic) svn:externals to include code from Github in a svn-hosted project

Tags: git, svn, github, git-svn, svn-externals

We use Subversion locally, and we're working on a project that uses a fork of Fluent NHibernate, which is hosted on Github.

I'd like it set up so that a single svn checkout will retrieve everything necessary to build the project, but maintain the ability to fetch HEAD updates from github.

Is there any way I can pull code from the Git repository as though it was an svn:external dependency? Can I just check the .git folder into our Subversion repository and just run git fetch when I need to, then svn commit the results?

Comment: Couldn't the method behind SVN vendor branches be used for this? http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch07s05.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

http://github.com/blog/626-announcing-svn-support says

```
$ svn checkout https://github.com/USER/PROJECT/trunk
```

works. So use that URL for your `svn:externals`.

Comment: how about a github specific tag/branch?

Comment: +1. Also, GitHub updated their svn support so I updated the URL. https://github.com/blog/966-improved-subversion-client-support

Comment: @farinspace See the new URL: try adding `/branches/FOO` or `/tags/BAR`

Comment: How about a specific revision number?  There is no such thing as a "revision number" in git, but this seems like the sort of thing that lots of people might have a need for.

Answer (score 0):

- **Specific commit**: You need to find the appropriate revision number from the git repository using the SHA1 hash:

  ```
  $ git svn find-rev <sha1>
  ```

  Next, use the [peg revision syntax](http://[3]:%20http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) for the revision number in your svn:externals definition.

  ```
  https://github.com/<user>/<project>@<revision>
  ```
- **Specific tag** (from @orip's comment):

  ```
  https://github.com/<user>/<project>/tags/<tag>
  ```
- **Specific branch** (from @orip's comment):

  ```
  https://github.com/<user>/<project>/branches/<branch>
  ```